# Is it possible to read-lock a table/row in a transaction without first updating it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I'm trying to give exclusive read access to a critical section amongst concurrent threads. However, a **serializable isolation level** doesn't suffice because a read-block doesn't occur until an update is made, not after the initial read when it is needed to avoid the race condition below.

```
DECLARE @x INT

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    -- need to read-block other threads here
    SELECT @x = field1 FROM transtest WHERE id = 1;

    SET @x = @x + 1;

    UPDATE transtest SET field1 = @x WHERE id = 1;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

**Aside from issuing a "benign" update to trigger a read-lock, as in the following example, is there a more direct way to obtain it?**

```
UPDATE transtest 
SET field1 = (SELECT field1 FROM transtest WHERE id = 1) 
WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: `SELECT @x = field1 FROM transtest WITH(ROWLOCK) WHERE id = 1;`?  *(It's been a long time since I tried this and I don't have SQL Server at hand to try concurrency testing...)*  *(I recall that `PAGE LOCK` can be better, not sure if that's still the case...)*

Comment: SERIALIZABLE is *always* sufficient to be safe. It simulates singled-threaded database access. But you might get deadlocks which you can safely retry.

Comment: @usr This particular case seemingly allows for a "lost update". If Thread-2 reads `field1` into `x` before Thread-1 writes an `UPDATE` (which it possible since T1's `SELECT` doesn't issue a read-lock), then an increment is lost.

Comment: No, then a deadlock occurs because T2 will have read-locked the row when reading it. Any data read under SERIALIZABLE is stabilized through read locks.

Comment: @usr Oh right, you already said that, thanks for clarifying. I think I was assuming that whichever thread obtains the read lock first "wins" and gets to write unconditionally, while blocking other threads from also writing (which made me ponder why reads didn't read-block)... It turns out that I forgot to update after the increment anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just do this?

```
UPDATE transtest SET field1 = field1 + 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

OP said other stuff is going on.  I think this will do it.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    -- need to read-block other threads here
    SELECT @x = field1 + 1 
    FROM transtest with (rowlock uplock)
    WHERE id = 1;

    //other stuff

    UPDATE transtest SET field1 = @x WHERE id = 1;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: At a guess, it's a simplified example, rather than filling the OP with unrelated crap?

Comment: This sql is actually executed from a DAL, which I've kept to basic reads (selects) and writes (inserts/updates). So reads and writes are done sequentially as separate select and update statements. Although, it does support arbitrary sql command strings now that I think about it. However, the "incrementing" is done in assembly library code, which computes the values from the initial read.